# How to get attribute value in <a> element?

Tags: ionic-framework, attributes, ionic4

How can i take the value of the **data-set** attribute or change it in the link with the following structure:
`<a href='#' data-set='22'>Text</a>`

I know that in jquery I can use the:
`$('a').attr ('data-set');`

And to change your content:
`$('a').attr ('data-set', '01');`

But in Ionic4 i am not getting it, already researched and can not exactly that.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**:

I did it this way:

```
<ion-input #myInput data-set="01"></ion-input>

@ViewChild ('myInput', { read: ElementRef }) myInput: ElementRef;


ngAfterContentInit() {
   console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.dataset.dta1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In native JavaScript you can just do

To get the attribute use `document.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-set');` 
And to set the attribute use `document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('data-set', '01');`

Comment: But, how can do this in IONIC4 with Angular structure?? This is my problem.

Comment: Here's some details about angular attribute https://www.techiediaries.com/add-access-html-data-attribute-angular/

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

assuming you have `<a href='#' id="mylink" data-set='22'>Text</a>`

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('#mylink');

//get
el.dataset.set

//set
el.dataset.set = "01"
```

Note: HTMLElement.dataset may not be supported in some browsers, please test it before put it into production

Comment: But, how can do this in IONIC4 with Angular structure?? This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

in **HTML** file,

```
<ul>
  <li #messageEl *ngFor="let message of messages" [attr.data-message-id]="message.id">
{{ message.text }}
<br><button (click)="logMessageId(messageEl)">Console Log </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in **.ts** file,

```
logMessageId(el){
  let messageId = el.getAttribute('data-message-id');
  //let messageId = el.dataset.messageId;
  console.log("Message Id: ", messageId);
}
```